# php, что делать если удалил composer.lock

Tags: php, json, composer, lock

Что делать если удалил composer.lock? Есть composer.json, но как восстановить composer.lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я знаю он создается в процессе работы `composer` с конфигурационным файлом `composer.json`. Так что все что Вам нужно сделать `composer update`.

Comment: во время этой команды вылетает: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67108864 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

Comment: Что ж там за пакеты у вас такие? 1.5GB мало)